# Pass and access params in a ReactJS link

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass params in a ReactJS link, and access them in the component I'm linking to. This is what I tried:

In the `router`:

```
<Route path="/NextComponent/:paramName" component={NextComponent}> <NextComponent/></Route>
```

In the table where the links are:

```
<Link
   to={{
     pathname: "/NextComponent/paramvalue",
     state: { paramName: 'paramvalue' }
  }}
>my link text</Link>
```

I tried retrieving it like this in `NextComponent`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
}
```

Then in `componentDidMount`:

```
async componentDidMount() {
   const data = this.props;
   this.setState({ data });
   console.log(data);
   console.log(this.props);
}
```

But the `props` is an empty object. I tried looking for anything else in the component, like

```
console.log(this.search);
console.log(this.props.match);
console.log(this.props.location);
console.log(this.paramName);
```

but they're all `undefined`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059249/4597596 to access the params.

Comment: `match` has a `params` object in it, have you looked there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create dynamic routes with react-router-dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058879/how-to-create-dynamic-routes-with-react-router-dom)

Comment: No, none of these works. Like I say in the question, the `props` object is empty. @JohnRuddell, `this.match` is `undefined`.

Comment: Ok, the the issue is you aren't connecting the component to the routes. have you looked at `withRouter`?

Answer (score 0):

[Route](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)

> **Warning:** `<Route children>` takes precedence over both `<Route component>` and `<Route render>` so don’t use more than one in the same
>   .

**ROUTE PROPS**

I think due to this your wrapped child components take precedence and aren't getting `route-props` since you are also specifying a `component`. Try not specifying a `component` prop **AND** a wrapped child component.

```
<Route
  path="/NextComponent/:paramName"
  component={NextComponent}
>
  <NextComponent/> // This one doesn't receive route-props (i.e. match, location, etc..)
</Route>
```

Specify one or the other

```
<Route
  path="/NextComponent/:paramName"
  component={NextComponent} // will receive route-props
/>

// or

<Route
  path="/NextComponent/:paramName"
>
  <NextComponent/> // needs to use hooks to access route-props
</Route>
```

**SENDING ROUTE PARAMS**

The string literal `"/NextComponent/:paramName"` isn't a pathname you can match.

When pushing the route you can't pass route parameters in state, you need to properly format the route pathname (i.e. the URL). This is commonly done using string interpolation.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/NextComponent/${paramvalue}`
  }}
>
  my link text
</Link>
```

Or more succinctly using the standard `to` as a string

```
<Link to=`/NextComponent/${paramvalue}`>my link text</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew. But how do I now retrieve the param?

Comment: [`props.match.params`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) if passed as prop, either by rendering it directly on `component` or `render` prop from the `Route` or by decorating your component with the `withRouter` HOC, or by using the [useParams](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams), `const { paramName } = useParams()`.