# Get all document from firestore and then create route to them

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The sermon collection contains many documents that contain:

1. a link to the picture from the video
2. title of the sermon from YouTube
3. date of the sermon
4. and a link to the sermon on YouTube.

I want to get the date to display on the page and create its own route for each.

Comment: You can use react-router-dom package.
please visit here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058879/how-to-create-dynamic-routes-with-react-router-dom

Comment: You can use react-router-dom package.
You can find here.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058879/how-to-create-dynamic-routes-with-react-router-dom)

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-router dynamically create routes for each date. if you have not looked into react-router yet, it's work looking into it. [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but can you show how do this? I get information from the database then in state and display it on the page using sermons.map (sermon => {<img src = {sermon.img}, etc. There are many pictures, but the img object is one

Comment: can you show me object structure of the data in state or fetched from firestore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026503/get-all-doc-data-from-collection-seremon-firestore