# Get all doc data from collection seremon firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
function Sermons() {

    const [{globalSeremon}, dispatch] = useStateValue()
    const [seremons, setSeremons] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('sermons')
        .orderBy("date", "desc")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {

            const localseremons = []
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                localseremons.push(doc.data())
            })
            setSeremons(localseremons)

        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
        })

    
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <div className='container-lg seremon_container'>
                {seremons.map(seremon => (
                            <a className='seremon_link' key={seremon.img} onClick={addSeremon}>
                                <div className='seremon'>
                                    <img className='seremon_img contai' src={seremon.img}/>
                                    <div className='details'>
                                        <h3 className='seremon_title'>{seremon.title}</h3>
                                        <p className='seremon_detail seremon_date'>
                                            {seremon.date}
                                        </p> 
                                        <p className='seremon_worship seremon_detail'>{seremon.worship}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**And also if you can add an onClick function to the seremon.link to find out which of the seremon the user clicked on**

[image: link to firestore photo [1]:]

Comment: I dont understand what your question is ?

Comment: The firestore has a collection of seremon and there are many documents that contain 1) a link to a picture from a YouTube video 2) the title of the sermon 3) the date, etc. I want to get it to display all the data (I have already done that) and track the click, I cannot do this. When I add onClick function it will output all documents to the console. Helpppp please. If you can say something differently - say

Comment: so if i understand correctly, what you want is keep the number of click a seremon had on its youtube link ?
In other words, implement your addSeremon method right ?
And you want to display in your firestore document (every document will get a new field named 'clicked': number. Am I right ?

Comment: I want to 1) output seremon to the page (I did it) 2) for each seremon create a Route And if it is possible to track which of the seremon the user clicked on Please help if you can