# How to create dynamic route which may or may not have a route? React router

Tags: android

I need to create route which dont a have route...but
In some situation this route can have a dynamic data

Example in some situation is

[www.test.com/home](http://www.test.com/home)

When can be

[www.test.com/home/1](http://www.test.com/home/1)

/1 is id.

I need this dynamic route

Comment: Check this related questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058879/how-to-create-dynamic-routes-with-react-router-dom

Comment: So you are saying the same route should work for /home and /home/1 ?

Comment: @MridulGupta yes same route should work for /home and /home/1. Is that impossible ?

Comment: @Cinovates it's possible, what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router

Answer (score 1):

You can use route `/home` for the main component and route `/home/:id` for the some-entity-component with `id = :id`.
Or use only route `/home/*` for any routes started with `/home`

Usually it looks like:

```
const definitions  = [
  {
    Component: Entities,
    path: '/entities',
  }, 
  {
    Component: Entity,
    path: '/entities/:id',
  },
];
```

OR with one route

```
const definitions  = [
  {
    Component: Entities,
    path: '/entities/*',
  }, 
];
```