# A way for better handling routes in React

Tags: reactjs, routes

I was wondering if there is a way for better handling react routes. I am trying to create a book store with different pages. Whenever someone clicks on a specific book, it redirects to a page with some descriptions about the author and buttons to proceed with the purchase. These are my routes:

```
<Routes>
              {/* DASHBOARD */}
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
              {/* PAGES */}
              <Route path="/books" element={<Books />} />
              <Route path="/authors" element={<Authors />} />
              <Route path="/foryou" element={<Foryou />} />
              <Route path="/bestsellers" element={<Bestsellers />} />
              <Route path="/top100" element={<Top100 />} />
              <Route path="/userProfile" element={<UserProfile />} />
              {/* CATEGORIES */}
              <Route path="/hardscifi" element={<Hardscifi />} />
              <Route path="/cyberpunk" element={<Cyberpunk />} />
              <Route path="/spaceopera" element={<Spaceopera />} />
              <Route path="/steampunk" element={<SteamPunk />} />
              <Route path="/androidsrobots" element={<AndroidsRobots />} />
              {/*SINGLE BOOKS*/}
              <Route path="/sea" element={<Sea/>}/>
              <Route path="/upgrade" element={<Upgrade/>}/>
            </Routes>
```

The last routes refers to specific books. The question is, If I have millions of books in my app, Will I have millions of pages in my routes? I know this may sound like a silly question but I have no idea how it works.

I am getting all the data from this api

Comment: Take a look at dynamic routing, something like `path="/books/:bookid"` where you use the book-id to gather required info of that book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create dynamic routes with react-router-dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058879/how-to-create-dynamic-routes-with-react-router-dom)

Answer (score 0):

Building off @Ostone0's comment, have a single component (eg `<Book />`) that will use the `:bookid` param. You can use `react-router-dom`'s `useParams` hook to grab this value and load the requested book from your API.

App.js / Wherever you're routing from

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/books" element={<Books />} />
    <Route path="/books/:bookId" element={<Book />} />
</Routes>
```

Book.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Book() {
  const { bookId } = useParams()
  const [book, setBook] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
        if (!bookId) {
              alert('Error - no book selected')
              return
        }
        loadBook()
  }, [])

  const loadBook = async () => {
        try {
              const res = await fetch('http://yourapi.com/books')
              setBook(await res.json())
        } catch (e) {
              alert('Error loading book.')
        }
  }
  
  if (!book) {
        return <div>Loading book...</div>
  }
  return (
        <div>
              <h1>{book.title}</h1>
              {/* more book stuff */}
        </div>
  )
}
```

So now one book component serves as the single template for your millions of books